# DOS batch script works -- almost: moving selected files AND folders off the desktop

Tags: batch-file

I've gotten excellent help here recently, which I keenly appreciate.  Thanks to the breadth of knowledge on this site I've been able to cobble together some code which is trivial in its purpose, yet important for my environment.

The simplified purpose, and my problem:

The goal: for the current user, upon login to Windows, move all files and folders into a desktop folder named "Archive" [create the latter if necessary].  (The content moved is put into a dynamically created subfolder based on timestamp.)

The existing problem:  the code fails to move desktop folders into the (deskstop) Archive folder.  (I obviously don't want to move the Archive folder itself.)

Any insight / solution would be hugely helpful.  (PS if at all possible I wish to keep to DOS bat files vs more complex languages.)

My current .BAT file [note- the many variables are for initial debugging]:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
:: Establish desired base name for the primary desktop archive folder

set ARCH=Archives

 ::  Establish logged in user path to desktop

set G=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop

 :: Now, if "Archives" folder does not yet exist on desktop, create it

if not exist "%G%\Archives" mkdir "%G%\%ARCH%

 :: Consolidate pathname <user\desktop\Archives> into single variable (TARGET)

set TARGET=%G%\%ARCH%

 :: Create [date+time specific] subfolder name -- two steps - build string, then assign 

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "MS=%dt:~15,3%"


 :: Set variable to hold new name Archives\Saved-<time-specific-subfolder> in final form 

set "savedirname=Saved-%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%-%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

 :: Finally, append new foldername to user-specfic path (TARGET)

set MoveTo=%TARGET%\%savedirname%

 :: Create final targeted destination folder - complete pathname

 mkdir %MoveTo%

 :: Move all desktop files/folders EXCEPT the Archives folder into the targeted destination

 for %%i in (%G%\*.*) do move %%i %MoveTo%
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's actually not a "DOS" batch file as you are working on Windows obviously... anyway, you are using a `for` loop which enumerates files only; to enumerate directories, use a second `for` loop but with the `/D` switch provided (type `for /?` in command prompt for details); this will also return the `Archives` folder, so you need to exlude it by an `if /I` statement (type `if /?` for help; I recommend the `/I` switch to do a case-insensitive comparison as file/dir. names are case-insensitive on Windows also)...

Comment: Aschipfl : thank you for the insightful suggestions from May 6.  Unfortunately I've been pulled away for a few days and am just now getting back to this.  I've been trying to decipher the addition of an extra for-loop to grab directories (not files), but am having trouble understanding exactly how to specify "for all folders except FOLDERX move the folders into...".  Could you elabaorate a bit more on the synatx I need?  Gratefully appreciated . . . -Saguaro

Comment: I was thinking about `for /D %%j in ("%G%\*") do if /I not "%%j"=="Archives" move "%%~j" "%MoveTo%"`; you should use the same quotation for your `for %%i` loop; another thing: in your line `if not exist "%G%\Archives" mkdir "%G%\%ARCH%` (where you forgot the closing `"`), why are you not using variable `%ARCH%` consistently?

Answer (score 0):

> (PS if at all possible I wish to keep to DOS bat files vs more complex languages.)

This isn't the answer you ask for, but this is PowerShell (v4) code to do what your code does:

```
$arch = "Archives"
$desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$saveDirName = Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"

$target = "$desktop\$arch\$saveDirName"
mkdir $target -Force

dir $desktop | where Name -ne $arch | Move-Item -Destination $target -Force
```

Is it really "more complex" than your original code?

- Your original code guesses that `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` is the desktop - that's incorrect if the desktop is redirected, it could be `\\fileserver\users\username\desktop\`. It's incorrect if the OS is installed in a foreign language, in Swedish it's `%UserProfile%\Skrivbord`. Asking Windows where the desktop is gets the correct location every time. My code does this.
- PowerShell handles dates sanely. No string manipulation, no WMI calls, one formatting string for what format you want.
- I use the `mkdir -Force` option, it can make folders two levels deep in one go, and it does nothing if they already exist. No need for IF NOT EXIST... tests, although you could do them with `Test-Path`. You could use this approach in the batch file, mkdir can make multiple nested folders there, too.
- NB. your code has a bug where you check for `"%G%\Archives"` but you `mkdir "%G%\%ARCH%`. If %ARCH% is meant to be configurable, they could differ.

And this version does the folder moving which you are asking about that your code doesn't yet do, and will need another abuse of a `for` loop to handle.

This script is half the amount of code, more readable because it directly does what it needs instead of wandering out to wmi and string manipulation and `for` loops for string handling, it's more correct in more situations, more resilient, *and* does the extra things your original doesn't.

Yes it's a bigger and more complex language - that's how it makes things easier for you, because it can do more things directly.

Comment: TesselatingHeckler:  thank you so very much for not only the code but the simplified and direct explanations.  I would like to implement  this, but I'm  totally unfamiliar with powerscript.  How I go about executing this? I need to run automatically when the current user logs into his/her account.  (The platforms are Win7.)   I'm  very much hoping to be able to test this today if possible.  Again - thank you!

Comment: You can configure PowerShell logon in Group Policy in the same place you can configure batch file logon scripts - https://4sysops.com/archives/configuring-logon-powershell-scripts-with-group-policy/ - although with Win 7 your computers will have PowerShell 2 by default, and that's very old now, this script might not work in PSv2.  (It might not work in PSv4, I didn't test it).

Answer (score -1):

```
set fldr="%userprofile%\desktop\archive\%date:/=%%time::=%"
md %fldr%
For /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /a-d /b "%userprofile%\desktop" ^| Findstr /I /v /c:"archive"') Do @echo move "%userprofile%\desktop\%A" %fldr%
```

The above is all you need.

Batch isn't a programming language, although IBM engineers added programming like features.

It designed for copying files and starting programs. It becomes a stupid language if used as a programming language.

Use `%%A` in a batchfile. Remove `Echo` to have it actually move files.

To get the doc folder, which is always called desktop (explorer substitutes localised names for real names via the desktop.ini file)

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A
```

Use `%%A` in a batchfile.